# Windows 11 Thinkpad Bluetooth problems when using a Mediatek MT7921 WiFi/BT device

Tags: usb, bluetooth, sleep, windows-11

I'm the proud owner of a brand new ThinkPad P14s Gen2 AMD running Windows 11 Pro (upgraded from stock Windows 10 by the reseller). I have a very strange problem:

As soon as the PC enters/wakes sleep mode the Bluetooth adapter 'crashes' and is thusly uninstalled from the device manager tree by Windows. Instead a faulty USB device is shown:

> “Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)”

All this can be reverted by uninstalling both(!) the faulty USB device and the WLAN adapter (which works like a charm), shutting down and restarting (no reboot, that doesn't work). After this procedure Bluetooth works again no problems until the next sleep.

Drivers and Windows 11 are current. I'm searching the web for some days now and found no usable soluion. The Windows Bluetooth troubleshooter does not find any problems (...) and reinstalling Windows (preserving all my files) did not solve the problem either (but made the crashing less predictable, also fixed problems with pairing).

The kernel of the current release of Ubuntu unfortunately does not support the used Mediatek MT7921 WiFi/BT card yet (the Bluetooth part of it anyway) and my Linux-Fu does not support kernel doctoring in live systems…

The event viewer also is of no big help. I'm actually not thinking that this is related to hardware as sometimes BT 'survives' sleep mode. Also since reinstalling Windows 11 Bluetooth can be switched on and off by the normal Windows soft switch no problems (which irregularly also caused the adapter to crash).

All this seems to be related to some energy management problem, but changing the energy management options in device manager for the BT adapter does not change the behavior.

I'm sure there's something I missed. I'd really appreciate some hints on how to deal with this.

Comment: Run System Update (Lenovo) and be sure to pick of BIOS.  I have an X230 on Windows 11 and Bluetooth is working well.  Also open a warranty case with Lenovo.

Comment: ...did that, forgot to mention. BIOS also is current 1.13
...and SystemUpdate does not find any driver updates as of now... :/

Comment: I would file a warranty support claim.

Comment: yeah sure... You think it's hardware?

Comment: It could be because Windows 11 works fine with Bluetooth.

Comment: ...it does! Until it decides it's time to save some energy... ;)
The reason I dod not file a warranty case is that they only care for the hardware.

Comment: So, this is not "brand new", this is refurbished at best, and from your description of a "reseller", probably not that either. Please remove this statement and make it more clear in the question itself this is a new-to-you used computer. Also, can you restore to the original OS?

Comment: "So, this is not "brand new" - yes it was.
"this is refurbished at best" - no, new out of the box.
"make it more clear in the question itself this is a new-to-you used computer" - no because it was indeed new. "Also, can you restore to the original OS" Probably, but not necessary because changing the WIFI module to an Intel AX210 fixed all issues.